Why top mounted propellers aren't more common?
If having a longer propeller increases efficiency(lower disk loading), why aren't there more GA airplanes with top mounted propellers like the Chotia Weedhopper ultralight, thus enabling the increase of prop diameter while keeping ground clearance, but Instead the norm is a middle mounted prop like the Cessna 172.

source

A high propeller location can usually be found in seaplanes. Examples range from the Dornier Libelle to the Canadair CL-415.

Dornier Libelle or Dornier A (picture source)

Canadair CL-415 (picture source)
The obvious reason is to keep the propeller away from spray water, but another reason becomes only obvious when we look what happened to landplanes with high mounted engines. One example is mentioned in Bill Gunston's book "Back to the Drawing Board", which presents a range of unfortunate design mistakes. The one with the high engines is the series of Blériot 67 to 75, a series of four-engined biplane bombers from 1916 to 1919 with two of their four engines mounted in the upper wing.

Blériot 73 (picture source)
The Blériot company even patented this engine arrangement since it minimized the yawing moment resulting from engine failure. However, it soon became apparent that for take-off only the lower engines could be run at full power - adding full power to the upper engines would had tipped the airplane over.
Seaplanes with their long hull offer much better pitch stability during their ground run than tailwheel designs, so only they could afford a high engine position. Both still suffer from severe pitch trim changes with power changes, requiring more attention from the pilot and a larger horizontal tail.
Still, your reasoning of using a larger propeller for better efficiency is sound. What has been done to integrate large propellers can be seen in the late WW I period, when increasing engine power made the gyro effects of rotary engines so severe that geared engines were developed where the cylinders rotate in one direction and the propeller in the opposite direction. As a consequence, the propeller had only half the RPM in air as it had with the cylinder block. This gave great propeller efficiency, but also big propeller diameters, so airplanes with those engines needed a high landing gear. Below is a picture of a Roland D XVI with a Siemens & Halske III counter-rotating rotary engine from 1918 (source). This was an excellent fighter aircraft for its time with almost no gyro coupling.

Now the engine is in line with the longitudinal axis of the airplane, but still way above the ground, so the resulting pitching moment makes ground handling tricky. Pilots preferred smaller props with less sensitive pitch reactions to throttle changes, and this carried over to modern tricycle designs which, especially when using ungeared engines, use smaller, faster spinning props.
A large prop will need a reduction gear and a higher landing gear, which both add weight and cost. Why you want a high-revving engine in airplanes is explained here, so low RPM engines don't qualify. The compromise is to use an ungeared engine and suffer the lower efficiency of the smaller propeller, but benefit from the lower mechanical complexity and weight of an ungeared engine.

interesting, your last point about the need for gear reduction is a good one nobody has motioned

Excellent, I'd love to see a jungmeister or yak55 powered by a modern variant of that contra rotary engine

@user721108 Both the Bücker 133 and the Yak 55 use radial engines. The ones with the severe gyro effects are called rotary engines.

ok my bad i misunderstood what's counter rotating in S&H III. prop and cylinders actually spin in the same direction

(i thought prop and cyl spun in opposite directions in S&H III, that could have make sense, and improve cooling btw)

@PeterKämpf  the propeller could have been attached to the crankshaft instead of the crankcase. rpm would still have been halved, but cooling would have been improved by taking advantage of the relative wind opposition between the direction of rotation of the cooling fins and that of the propeller blades. no idea where on SE to ask about that, nor if relevant at all.

@user721108 The invention of the NACA cowling has made rotating the cylinders for cooling superfluous. Only if you have several rows of cylinders AND poor internal aerodynamics will cooling be an issue. The cowling of the Roland D XVI anticipated the NACA cowling. Regarding the S&H III, Wikipedia has an animation showing how it worked.

The aeroplane is easiest to control if the thrust line intersects with the Centre of Gravity (CoG).

The propeller thrust in the ultralight is above the CoG (my estimation of it), and any change in thrust will create a pitching moment which will need to be compensated for with the pitch stick. Not much of an issue normally, except in situations like engine failure during takeoff etc. which will need to be failure analysed for passenger planes.
In the pictured ultralight the propeller slipstream is over the wing area, which helps in creating lift. So yeah, having the propeller in front of a high wing is a no-brainer actually.

Not quite. The aircraft is easiest to control if the thrust line intersects with the center of effective drag, not the COG. (I use easiest to control in the same sense that you meant.)

@A.I.Breveleri https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/65897/21091

Think of this in terms of a vector sum of thrust, weight, and drag.
At zero airspeed (like when starting a takeoff roll) the thrust of a top-mounted prop causes a nose-down pitching moment that the pilot has to trim away in order to get the AoA correct for best takeoff performance.
Then, as speed builds up, drag is nonzero and the center of pressure of the fuselage starts to add to the pitch-down condition, requiring more trimming.
When the plane leaves the ground, the pitching moment gets shifted  depending on exactly where the center of lift is relative to the center of gravity.
In a perfect world, you'd have the thrust line go through a point as close as possible to the CG, CoL and CoP (and have these locations be as close to one another as possible) so that during flight, you don't need to adjust pitch trim with changes in power setting- and at takeoff, you advance power and the plane naturally flies itself off the runway when the airspeed is right.

There are a few safety issues with this design:

If the engine is in the position like this ultralight it prevents the pilot from having any visibility above and ahead of the aircraft. This makes it much harder to see and avoid air traffic. In a more standard configuration you look over the engine, which blocks your view ahead and below to a certain extent, however when you are turning you can see what you are turning into, which is much safer
With a high mounted engine the thrust is always pushing the nose down, so if the engine quits the aircraft will have a tendency to pitch up. In a climb you'd need very quick reactions to get the nose down or you'd risk a stall


Regarding point 2. Does increasing the prop diameter helps alleviate this issue?
